# VBA in Excel: Runtime Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do the following. I have several spreadsheets that are named something like "ITT_198763" where the ITT part stays the same but the number changes. I also have one tab called program where the 6 digit number is imported on row 40 (hence the RngToSearch below). I need the program to 1) find the "ITT" sheet for a certain 6 digit number, 2) identify the corresponding row in the "Program" tab, and copy information from the "ITT" tab to row 41 of the identified column. I will be copying more information from the ITT sheet to the specified column, but for now I am just trying to get it to work once.

From the MsgBox, I know it identifies the correct prjNumber (the 6 digit number), but I get the runtime 1004 error on the line Set RngDest. Any help will be appreciated!

```
Sub Summary_Table()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim RngToSearch As Range, RngDest As Range
Dim foundColumn As Variant
Dim prjNumber

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

   If ((Left(wks.Name, 3) = "ITT")) Then

   prjNumber = Right(wks.Name, 6)
   MsgBox (prjNumber)

   Set RngToSearch = Sheets("Program").Range("C40:q40")
   foundColumn = Sheets("Program").Application.Match(prjNumber, RngToSearch, False)

   With Sheets("Program")
       Set RngDest = .Range(1, foundColumn) 'Project Name
   End With

   If Not IsError(foundColumn) Then
      wks.Range("E2").Copy RngDest
   End If

   End If

Next wks


End Sub
```

I tried the .cell instead with the following code (all else is the same) and now get runtime error 13 on the Set RngDest line:

```
Set RngToSearch = Sheets("Program").Range("C40:q48")
foundColumn = Sheets("Program").Application.Match(prjNumber, RngToSearch.Rows(1), False)

With Sheets("Program")
   Set RngDest = RngToSearch.Cells(1, foundColumn) 'Project Name
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Yuo are getting that error because `foundColumn` has an invalid value. Step through the code and see what is the value of `foundColumn`

Here is an example which works.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim RngDest As Range, RngToSearch As Range

    foundColumn = 1

    Set RngToSearch = Sheets("Program").Range("C40:q40")

    Set RngDest = RngToSearch.Cells(1, foundColumn)

    Debug.Print RngDest.Address
End Sub
```

Add `MsgBox foundColumn` before the line `Set RngDest = RngToSearch.Cells(1, foundColumn)` and see what value do you get. I guess the line

`foundColumn = Sheets("Program").Application.Match(prjNumber, RngToSearch, False)`

is not giving you the desired value. Here is the way to reproduce the error.

[image]

**EDIT (Solution)**

You need to handle the situation when no match is found. Try something like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim RngDest As Range, RngToSearch As Range

    Set RngToSearch = Sheets("Program").Range("C40:q40")

    foundcolumn = Sheets("Program").Application.Match(1, RngToSearch, False)

    If CVErr(foundcolumn) = CVErr(2042) Then
        MsgBox "Match Not Found"
    Else
        Set RngDest = RngToSearch.Cells(1, foundcolumn)

        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: An alternative is to use *Range Object Find Method* don't you think?

Comment: Yes, you can use that as well. I was trying to stick to what OP was using :)

Comment: Hello! Thanks! I agree with you that the foundColumn is the problem, but not because there is no match. It is because something is wrong in the foundcolumn formula. I need found column to identify the column where the 6 digit number from prjNumber and the 6 digit number that is already in row 40 match. I can guarantee that, right now, they all have a match, so it is the formula for foundcolumn that is wrong. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: did you try to add a message box to display the value of `foundcolumn` as I suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `Cells` function, which has the prototype `.Cells([RowIndex], [ColumnIndex])`.  The `Range` function takes either a string with a range name (like `"A1"`, or a named range), or other range references.

Comment: Hello, I tried the new code above but its still not working, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Found column was the problem. Combining that with the help from the other commenters, the following works:

```
Sub Summary_Table()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim RngToSearch As Range, RngDest As Range
Dim foundColumn As Variant
Dim prjNumber

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If ((Left(wks.Name, 3) = "ITT")) Then

prjNumber = Right(wks.Name, 6)
MsgBox (prjNumber)

Set RngToSearch = Sheets("Program").Range("a40:q48")
foundColumn = Sheets("Program").Rows(40).Find(what:=prjNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Column
MsgBox (foundColumn)


With Sheets("Program")
   Set RngDest = RngToSearch.Cells(2, foundColumn) 'Project Name
   Debug.Print RngDest.Address
End With

If Not IsError(foundColumn) Then
    wks.Range("E3").Copy RngDest
End If

End If

Next wks


End Sub
```